# How to update viewport after deleting data from Firestore cloud interface without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, google-cloud-firestore

I'm updating a form using jQuery and when I delete data from Firestore interface it doesn't automatically reflect in my viewport without refreshing the page. I am looking for a way to have the data get real-time updates from Cloud Firestore.

```
 //Update button function
$('.save-button').on('click', function (event) {
    $('train-table').empty();
    event.preventDefault();
    //takes in form inputs
    var timetable = {
        name: $('.name-input').val(),
        destination: $('.destination-input').val(),
        frequency: $('.frequency-input').val(),
    }

    // Add new documents with a generated id.
    var addDoc = firestore
        .collection('train-schedule')
        .add({ timetable })
        .then(function (ref) {
            try {
                console.log("Status- Saved with ID: ", ref.id);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Got an error", error);
            }
        });
});
//get real time updates
getRealTimeUpdates = function () {
    trainCollection.onSnapshot(function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            var myData = doc.data().timetable;
            console.log("Train Id: ", doc.id);
            $(".train-table").append(
                "<tr><td id='name-col'>" + myData.name +
                "<td id='destination-col'>" + myData.destination +
                "<td id='frequency-col'>" + myData.frequency + "</td></tr>");
        });
    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });
}
getRealTimeUpdates();
```

});

I expect the viewport to update when data is deleted from the Firestore interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're only ever appending data to your HTML. So when there's any change (even when a document gets deleted), you just add HTML for all the remaining documents to the end your table.

The simple solution is to clear your table before re-rendering its contents:

```
trainCollection.onSnapshot(function (snapshot) {
    $(".train-table").clear(); // clear the existing documents before rerendering
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        var myData = doc.data().timetable;
        console.log("Train Id: ", doc.id);
        $(".train-table").append(
            "<tr><td id='name-col'>" + myData.name +
            "<td id='destination-col'>" + myData.destination +
            "<td id='frequency-col'>" + myData.frequency + "</td></tr>");
    });
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

A more efficient way would be to actually check what was changed by looking at [`QuerySnapshot.docChanges`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docChanges) and make more granular updates to the HTML based on that. Also see the [documentation on listening for changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).